# Calculator script written in Python printing inputted numbers, not executing operations

Tags: python

I am in the process of creating a calculator script in Python, which will take two numbers from the user, perform a mathematical operation on them (add, subtract etc) defined by the user. When I run the script (from within the PyCharm IDE), instead of doing the operation, it just outputs both the numbers. For example, If I were to input the numbers "2" and "7" along with the operation "multiply", the expected result would be "14" but the actual output is "27"

I am using python version 3.4.0, and PyCharm as my IDE as mentioned above

Below is all the code from my script:

```
from math import sqrt

greeting = "Welcome to calculator!"
print(greeting)
loop = 0

#Defines methods for mathematical operations: add, subtract etc.
def add(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 + num2
    return ans


def subtract(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 - num2
    return ans


def multiply(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 * num2
    return ans


def divide(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 / num2
    return ans


def exponent(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 ** num2
    return ans


def square_root(num1):
    ans = sqrt(num1)
    return ans


def get_num():
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "ans":
        num = ans
        return ans
    else:
        return num

#Gets input from the user, executes the appropriate operation and prints the answer
while loop == 0:
    operation = input("Enter an operation: ")
    if operation == "add" or "+":
        num1 = get_num()
        num2 = get_num()
        ans = add(num1, num2)
        print(ans)

    elif operation == "subtract":
        num1 = get_num()
        num2 = get_num()
        ans = subtract(num1, num2)
        print(ans)

    elif operation == "multiply":
        num1 = get_num()
        num2 = get_num()
        ans = multiply(num1, num2)
        print(ans)

    elif operation == "divide":
        num1 = get_num()
        num2 = get_num()
        ans = divide(num1, num2)
        print(ans)

    elif operation == "exponent":
        num1 = get_num()
        num2 = get_num()
        ans = exponent(num1, num2)
        print(ans)

    elif operation == "square root":
        num1 = get_num()
        square_root(num1)

    else:
        print("Operation not recognized.")
```

Comment: `or` does not work how you think it works.  I suggest you go back to your textbook/tutorial for that topic.

Comment: No, it's not homework, I'm just testing my Python abilities, and trying to learn more of the language. I'm learning Python on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your first `if statement` (addition) is evaluated, it should be:

```
operation == "add" or operation == "+":
```

Or as paul points out:

```
operation in ('add','+'):
```

will work too.

`or` conjugates two expressions and checks for their truthiness. There are only certain values that are expected to be false. "+" is not one of them. Once you do that: your `num1` and `num2` are strings... "2" + "7" is concatenated together as "27".

This line:

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
```

Should have num casted to an int:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: Or write it as `operation in ['add','+']`

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, I'll add that too my answer.

Comment: I made the suggested change to the way I get input, and it appears to have worked, thank you very much for your help!